# Angular/Flex:Setting max width of component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-flex-layout

I'm trying to create some sort of reddit-clone which shows posts and their content, but if the content is longer than a certain width, it should break and start on the new line. For some reason I can't get the max width to work. The width of the mat-card is the same as the body property of the post.

As far as I'm aware, I should change some values in fxFlex, I tried this but it still doesn't work.

**Post**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>
      {{post.author}}<br>
      {{post.creationDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
  </mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>
    {{post.body}}
  </p>
  </mat-card-content>
  <div style="text-align:right">
  <span><mat-icon>arrow_upward</mat-icon>{{post.upvotes}}</span><pre style="display: inline">  </pre>
  <span><mat-icon>arrow_downward</mat-icon>{{post.downvotes}}</span>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

**App component**

```
<app-navheader></app-navheader>
<div 
  fxLayout="column wrap"
  fxLayout.xs="column"
  fxLayoutGap="0.5%"
  fxLayoutAlign="center center"      
>
  <div 
    class="post"
    *ngFor="let p of posts"
    fxFlex="0 0 calc(25%-0.5%)"
    fxFlex.xs="100%">
    <app-post [post]="p"></app-post>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From what I understand, is that you have an issue with the content inside of the mat-card that needs to be formatted correctly and wrap if needed.   they easiest way to do this is to setup similar rules with flexLayout but in a row-layout.  Just use flex-layout rules as you already did and style the mat-card as you like.  to make your life easier, set a back-ground color on each item you want to position (so you visually see what you are doing)

Comment: If you could create an example of the generated HTML + CSS with your question we could easily help you.

Comment: or a stackblitz angular example...